# R: ifelse turns numeric(0) into NA

Tags: r, if-statement, implicit-conversion

Can someone explain to me why the following happens?

```
ifelse(TRUE, numeric(0), 1)
> [1] NA
```

I would expect numeric(0) of course. 
I suspect that this is because ifelse is vectorized, e.g. the following works, but I don't understand exactly what is going on.

```
if (TRUE) numeric(0) else 1
#> numeric(0)
```

Comment: Looks like you can't have a vector of `numeric(0)`, see: `c(numeric(0), numeric(0))`. I suppose it tries to vectorize it in a way that is possible.

Comment: `ifelse()` returns a vector of the same length as the test so it can't return a zero length vector.

Comment: @H Isn't the length of the test in the example 1, not zero? Since `length(TRUE)` is 1.

Comment: @machine yes but length of numeric(0) is 0 so I guess it does something like
rep_len(numeric(0), 1)

Comment: @Sebastian I am just pointing out that the problem is not the length of the test, as suggested by H 1, but the length of numeric(0).

Comment: @H I am not sure and that is why I asked " Isn't the length of the test in the example 1, not zero?".  I certainly did not want to offend you or something. Sorry to apperently put your comment in wrong context. This is how I interpreted it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can access the implementation of `ifelse`, which is

```
function (test, yes, no) 
{
    if (is.atomic(test)) {
        if (typeof(test) != "logical") 
            storage.mode(test) <- "logical"
        if (length(test) == 1 && is.null(attributes(test))) {
           #... let's skip this part..
        }
    }
    else test <- if (isS4(test)) 
        methods::as(test, "logical")
    else as.logical(test)
    ans <- test
    len <- length(ans)
    ypos <- which(test)
    npos <- which(!test)
    if (length(ypos) > 0L) 
        ans[ypos] <- rep(yes, length.out = len)[ypos]
    if (length(npos) > 0L) 
        ans[npos] <- rep(no, length.out = len)[npos]
    ans
}
<bytecode: 0x00000123e6b7d3a0>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

So, yes, it is because `ifelse` is vectorized - specifically along the *condition* - and the return object `ans` is initialized as a vector of the same length as the condition.

The description of `ifelse` states

> ifelse returns a value with the same shape as test which is filled
>   with elements selected from either yes or no depending on whether the
>   element of test is TRUE or FALSE.

Let `test <- TRUE`. The interesting lines are

```
ypos <- which(test)
rep(numeric(0), length.out = 1)[ypos]
```

Comment: Why is the `length.out` argument set to `0` in your example? If we use `test <- TRUE`, then inside `ifelse()` we have `ans <- test; len <- length(ans); rep(yes, length.out = len)`. Shouldn't be the argument set to `1`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to adjust the function so that it returns `numeric(0)` in your situation you can change the `if(length(yes) == 1)` to `if (length(yes) == 0 | length(yes) == 1)` inside the function. This gives you:

```
ifelse2 <- function (test, yes, no) {
  if (is.atomic(test)) {
    if (typeof(test) != "logical") 
      storage.mode(test) <- "logical"
    if (length(test) == 1 && is.null(attributes(test))) {
      if (is.na(test)) 
        return(NA)
      else if (test) {
    if (length(yes) == 0 | length(yes) == 1) { # Here is what I changed
          yat <- attributes(yes)
          if (is.null(yat) || (is.function(yes) && identical(names(yat), 
                                                         "srcref"))) 
            return(yes)
        }
  }
      else if (length(no) == 1) {
        nat <- attributes(no)
        if (is.null(nat) || (is.function(no) && identical(names(nat), 
                                                          "srcref"))) 
          return(no)
      }
    }
  }
  else test <- if (isS4(test)) 
    methods::as(test, "logical")
  else as.logical(test)
  ans <- test
  len <- length(ans)
  ypos <- which(test)
  npos <- which(!test)
  if (length(ypos) > 0L) 
    ans[ypos] <- rep(yes, length.out = len)[ypos]
  if (length(npos) > 0L) 
    ans[npos] <- rep(no, length.out = len)[npos]
  ans
}
```

Trying it:

```
ifelse2(TRUE, numeric(0), 1)
> [1] numeric(0)
```

You can do the same with the `no` argument if it can be `numeric(0)` in your case, too.